# Why is the destructor called?

Tags: c++, destructor

I wrote a simple vector class which overloads assignment and addition operators. The code adds two vectors and prints vectors before and after the addition. Surprisingly destructor ~MyVector() is being called after the line c=a+b. I do not see the reason why is it so, as neither of objects a,b and c gets out of scope. Do you understand the reason for invocation of the destructor?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
  public:

  MyVector(int s)
  {
    size=s;
    a=new T[s];
  }

  ~MyVector()
  {
    delete[] a;
    size=0;
  };

  void freeVec()
  {
    cout<<"Calling destructor. a[0]= "<<a[0]<<endl;
    if(a!=NULL)
    {
      free(a);
      a=NULL;
    }
  }

  int getSize(void)
  {
    return size;
  }
  void setSize(int ss)
  {
    size=ss;
  }
  T &operator[](int i)
  {
    return a[i];
  }

  MyVector &operator=(MyVector mv)
  {
    if(this==&mv)
      return *this;
    for(int i=0;i<mv.getSize();i++)
      this->a[i]=mv[i];
    this->size=mv.getSize();
    return *this;
  }

  MyVector operator+(MyVector &mv)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      this->a[i]+=mv[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return *this;
  }

  private:
  int size;
  T *a;
};

int main(void)
{
  MyVector<int> a(3),b(3),c(3);

  a[0]=1;a[1]=2;a[2]=3;
  b[0]=4;b[1]=5;b[2]=6;
  cout<<"initial vector"<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<"  ";
  cout<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    cout<<b[i]<<"  ";
  cout<<endl;

  c=a+b;  

  cout<<"final vectors"<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<"  ";
  cout<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    cout<<b[i]<<"  ";
  cout<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    cout<<c[i]<<"  ";
  cout<<endl;

  cout<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you notice, this doesn't return a reference   `MyVector operator+(MyVector &mv)`

Comment: Yup, return a MyVector reference from your + operator and you'll be good.

Comment: Why are you using `free(a)` in your `freeVec()` function after calling `a = new T[s]`? You should be using `delete[]`.

Comment: @DubiousPusher: Actually that's wrong. Returning a refernce would cause problems once the `operator+` modifies `this` is fixed. It needs to return a copy.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I was assuming that this was the behavior the poster desired from his or her + operator, for whatever reason (essentially making the + operator behave as people typically expect the += to behave.) Assuming he or she wanted that behavior, returning *this is acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `a + b` returns a nameless temporary object that consequently gets copied to `c` (by the assignment operator) and then gets destructed. That's the destructor call that you see.

Also, your assignment operator receives it parameter *by value* (why???), which means that theoretically another copy can be created for that as well. Your compiler apparently optimized out that copy, which is why you see only one additional destructor call.

BTW, since you manually manage allocated memory in your object, it is a very good idea to implement copy constructor as well, in accordance with the "Rule of Three". The current version of the class (without copy constructor) can easily be used to build broken code specifically because the copy constructor is missing. In fact, your current code is already broken, since it uses compiler-provided copy constructor  for copying your class object. The only reason you don't see any crashes is because the compiler optimized out (elided) most of the copies and, probably, because you got lucky.

On top of that your implementation of binary `+` modifies the data stored in `*this` object (why???), meaning that `c = a + b` modifies `a`. This is not exactly what people expect to see as a typical behavior of binary `+` operator.

There are lots of other bizarre things in your code. For example, what is `freeVec` and why is it trying to use `free` on memory that is always allocated by `new[]`? Also, why does the destructor set `size` to `0`? What is the point of that?

Comment: Thanks a lot AndreyT. The freeVec method is included here by mistake, it is just a garbage of code testing/experimenting which I missed to remove before writing the code here. GNU g++ compiler reports compile error if I use parameter _by reference_ but not _by value_ in my assignment operator. I.e. if I use MyVector &operator=(myVector &mv) the compiler reports: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘c = MyVector<T>::operator+(MyVector<T>&) [with T = int; MyVector<T> = MyVector<int>]((* & b))’
but parameter _by value_ compiles fine.

Comment: The mentioned compiler error comes from inability of compiler to match return type of *operator+* with the type of the parameter of *operator=*. The combination MyVector &operator=(MyVector &mv) with MyVector &operator+(MyVector &mv) solves the compilation issue.

Comment: @Robin Robinovic: It doesn't really "solve" it, but rather arbitrarily "distorts" the code into some compilable form. The proper way to solve it is to declare the assignment as `MyVector &operator=(const myVector &mv)`. That `const` in reference parameter declaration is crucial. The absence of that `const` was what prevented your assignment operator from binding to temporary objects. With `const` it will be able to bind to temporaries, meaning that now you'll be able to return a temporary `MyVector` from `operator +`.

Comment: Moreover, your `operator +` should also be declared as `MyVector operator+(const MyVector &mv) const` (if you prefer to declare it as a member, instead of a standalone function). It is generally impossible to write meaningful code in C++ while refusing to properly and very meticulously place all those `const` qualifiers.

Answer (score 3):

Because your `MyVector operator+(MyVector &mv)` creates a copy (as it should do). This temporary copy is destroyed once it has been stored in `c`.

Note that modifying `this` in `operastor+` is not a great plan. You don't expect `a` to become the same value as `c` from `c = a + b;`.

Comment: It also modifies `this` which it probably shouldn't do.

Comment: @DavidBrown: True. Doesn't affect the question itself, but I have edited.

Comment: Indeed modifying *this* in operator= is not a great idea, but this code had just a learning/experimental purpose and is not intended for a production code. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In the line `c = a + b;` there are actually 2 operations. The first is the addition. They way you have implemented it, `a` is actually incremented by the value of `b`. A copy of `a` is then returned in the line `return *this;`. This copy is not yet assigned to `c`; it is a nameless temporary.

In the assignment call, this copy is passed by value, thereby creating another copy. However, with copy elision, I believe it's possible the second copy is optimized out, so in total 1 copy is created. Thus the input to the assignment operator is a copy of an object. That object would get destroyed when the assignment operator returns.

Somewhat orthogonal to your question, I want to point out that there are a number of issues with the way you have implemented the operators. Firstly, your `+` operator is modifying the object that it is associated with. In the line `c = a + b;` the value of `a` gets modified because of the line `this->a[i]+=mv[i];` in your function, which I believe is not your intended effect.

Secondly, in your implementation of the `=` operator, the lines

```
if(this==&mv)
  return *this;
```

are useless because mv was passed by value and will never have the same address as `this` anyway.

Comment: Indeed modifying *this* in operator= is not a great idea, but this code had just a learning/experimental purpose and is not intended for a production code. Thanks for answer!